# Facebook Open-Graph object linking and multiple posting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

1.
I've added my action and object to my app with facebook open graph.
I've looked out everywhere, but couldn't find how to have the object word be clickable and follow to a link.
I know it can be done as I've seen it done by instagram for instance:

John Doe took a photo with Instagram.

the 'photo' word is linked. I wish to know how to do that.

2.
Another thing I've looked everywhere but couldnt find:
How do i apply action on multiple objects in one post?
e.g. John Doe bought "Item A" and "Item B" via MyApp

I see the examples of the sentences in the dashboard action settings, and those sentences appear, so they should be possible to do, but I couldn't figure out how.

Thanks.
There examples of sentences

Answer (score 1):

Facebook handle the linking of the items and nouns automatically, depending on the action type. For example, if you are using the `Read` action on a `Article`, Facebook will automatically make the article in `"John Doe read "Article A" and "Article B" via MyApp` linked to the original articles.

If you create a custom `took` action and a `photo` object type, you can see how Facebook generates the links for Instagram's actions. In Instagram's case, the `photo` is the object, which will always include a link.

[image: Example]

Comment: You say the linking is done automatically, but that's not the case in my custom action/object. I've noticed when you use a built-in action and object, Facebook does link it, yet instagram uses a custom object and can still link it. The link in og:url is set ofcourse, yet not used in linking.

Comment: The `og:url` is not used in the object. The link from the object itself is used in the action. For example, if you are using action `read` and object `article`, the url would be the url of the article you posted to facebook (`news.reads?article=http://someurl.com`) not the `og:url`.

Comment: I understand, but this still doesn't work for me - no link attached to my object.
However, that link IS clickable through the image, title and description of the object in the post, just not the "object" from "User <action> object"

Comment: Can you provide information on the custom action and object you've created? I'll see if I can replicate the issue.

Comment: as long as you dont use a pre-built facebook action or object. Try to create a custom object and a custom action, and see if the object is linked and clickable.

Comment: That's what I said with regards to the custom action `took` and object `photo` in my original answer.